# OBIEE 11g: How do I display slices in pie chart from largest to smallest?

Tags: obiee

How do I display slices in `OBIEE 11g` pie chart in order?

I need to display a pie chart where slices should be from largest to smallest, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data in the "Criteria" tab. Either ASC or DESC - whatever you want.